# java, apache pulsar Topic partition

Tags: java, apache-pulsar, pulsar

If I have a topic called `var test = "test"`
and I create a bean:

```
@Bean(name = "test")
public Producer<Test> testProducer(PulsarClient pulsarClient){
    return pulsarClient.newProducer()
            .topic(test)
            .create();
}
```

The topic is created I want to partition, how?

Answer (score 1):

To create a topic with partitions you can either configure the following settings for the Pulsar Broker (if you are relying on automatic topic creation)

```
allowAutoTopicCreationType = partitioned
defaultNumPartitions = <N>
```

Alternatively you can use the Pulsar Admin and use `createPartitionedTopic`
https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/a165bda1d03e370f5efe1173134fb94e12b584b5/pulsar-client-admin-api/src/main/java/org/apache/pulsar/client/admin/Topics.java#L473-L475

However once a topic has been created (I assume non-partitioned) then there is no way to make it partitioned. It has to be partitioned at topic creation time.